# how does java deal with multiple jvm options?

Tags: java

during trial and error I found out that at least OpenJDK `java` seems to use the last defined option when specifying for example `-XX:MaxRAMPercentage`, but I was not able to find any documentation on that?

Did I miss something? I'd like to not rely on undocumented behaviour, but maybe it's a general understanding the JVM deals with it that way?

Generally I am trying to make JRE options overwriteable in my container entrypoint, over multiple levels (stage, app, service), and it seem I could rely on the last parameter being taken here.

Comment: Do you mean if you specify the same option on the command line multiple times? As far as I know how different implementations of Java deal with that is not officially specified, and behavior may change in future versions. I would not rely on one particular behavior that you see with the version of Java that you are using right now; when you upgrade Java later then it might suddenly do something else.

Comment: Ok, thx, that would then be like I feared the situation is... hrmpf.